# NE5532 as a Guitar Pedal Buffer

Tags: buffer, input-impedance, guitar-pedal, ne5532

I’ve been trying to better understand the NE5532 and wanted to try designing some circuits with it. I wanted to do a dual-supply non-inverting guitar pedal buffer, but I’m concerned about the input impedance of the NE5532. Is it possible to get the 500k-1M input impedance that is standard in these pedals? Should I build a FET buffer instead, or perhaps just use another op-amp with better specs suited to the job?

Comment: The ne5532 is not a good instrument amplifier as you have realized. It has low noise, so it is particularly useful for (inverting) low impedance audio amplification. If you insist on using ancient parts, then the TL072/82 is perhaps a more suitable choice in this context

Comment: @tobalt I didn’t realize the NE5532 was outdated. Do you have a recommendation for a newer low noise, but high impedance non-inverting op amp? Or all they all pretty good now a-days?

Comment: I wouldn't say outdated. It's still produced and used from many manufacturers, so it is **cheap** and does many things satisfactorily.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you should check is input bias current and input impedance:

[image]

The typical input impedance is given as 300k. If you plan to use this with a passive-pickup electric guitar *(the output impedance can be as high as 500k, especially for high-output humbuckers – expect at least 200k, and if you use the volume knob below the full this will increase further)* it's going to be a problem. Also the input bias currents can be as high as almost a microamp which means another perspective of the problem for a signal source (instrument) having hundreds of kOhms of output impedance.

So, apparently, this doesn't seem to be a good choice for direct connection of a guitar.

You should have a look at CMOS op amps or JFET-based op amps such as [TL08x](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/tl082.pdf). TL082 is quite popular and widely available.